# Alert on simple Drag and Drop Div area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, file

[image]

As like shown in the image I need a very simple alert when the file is dragged in the dotted area I have tried plugins but those are not matching my requirements.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form  id="uploadStudentsForm"  class="js-upload-form">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="uploadStudents"/>
<div class="upload-drop-zone" id="drop-zone">
    <div class="upload-wrapper"  id="csvFileDiv">
        <p>Upload Files</p>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" class="inputfile " id="js-upload-files" multiple aria-label="hidden">  
        <label for="csvFile">drag & drop or click here to add csv file </label>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I want simple js like when files drag and dropped in that div(`upload-drop-zone`) show `alert("file dropped")`

I dont know which one to use tried these:

1. sortable
2. draggale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `ondrop` event handler in the drop zone like below.`ondragover` is added to override browser's default drag behaviors.

```
<div class="upload-drop-zone" id="drop-zone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" >
    <div class="upload-wrapper"  id="csvFileDiv">
        <p>Upload Files</p>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" class="inputfile " id="js-upload-files" multiple aria-label="hidden">  
        <label for="csvFile">drag & drop or click here to add csv file </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

the functions should be like below

```
function drop(event){
 event.preventDefault();

 alert("file dropped");
}

function dragover(event){
 event.preventDefault();

}
```

Sample working fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/4ZYq3/186/

check this link here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop

Comment: i have tried this but not working if you are 100% sure can give some fiddle or working example

Comment: @AbdulWaheed check the fiddle

Comment: Trying the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery change function for that.

```
    $(document).on('change', "#js-upload-files", function(){
      alert('file dropped');
    });
```

Comment: With your solution `file` is opening in the current web page. I want `drag dropper not select(Choose file)`.

Comment: since you are using input field so that input value has been changed when  you are dropped file, then above script will be triggered.